# retrive column data from mysql and display in dynamic list view in HTML form?newone to mysql & php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, jquery-mobile

retrive name column from mysql database and display in dynamic list view of HTML form while clicking the name of list it shows other details(age,sex,address) for selected name in other HTML form....send some suggestion or example am new to mysql&php...

Comment: Looks more like a demand than a question.

Comment: send some code that you have already tried.

Comment: you might as well wanna order - "and do that now !"

Answer (score 0):

You can take idea from below example

1) create connection from database

```
// Here 'inmoti6_myuser' is username and password is 'mypassword'
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","inmoti6_myuser","mypassword");

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// We now need to select the particular database that we are working with
// In this example,database named inmoti6_mysite
mysql_select_db("inmoti6_mysite", $con);
```

2) Write query for get name and email of users

```
$query = "SELECT name,email FROM `users` ";

// Now that we have our Query, we will run the query against the database
// and actually grab all user's name and email
$data = mysql_query($query);

// We are now ready to print name. Below we will loop through our
// data and print them one by one.
// The while statement will begin the "looping"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    // for example, to print the user's name, we would use:
    $name = $row['name'];

    //to print the user's email, we would use:
    $email = $row['email'];

    echo 
        "<div style='margin:30px 0px;float:left:width:100%'>
             Name: $name<br />
             Email: $email<br />     
        </div> ";
}
mysql_close($con);
```